# ExtJs 4.2 ref-selector vs Ext.getcmp() vs Ext.ComponentQuery.query()

Tags: javascript, performance, extjs, extjs4.2, page-load-time

I was asked to develop a tab panel with 6 tabs, each having 30 to 40 elements. Each tab is acting as a form in accumulating the details of a person and the last tab is a Summary page which displays all the values entered in the first five tabs. I was asked to provide summary as a tab because, the user can navigate to summary tab at any instance and look at the details entered by him/ or glace the summary. i am following ExtJs MVC pattern. Payload is coming from / going to Spring MVC Application. (JSON)

Using tab change event in controller and if the newtab is summary I am rendering the page with show hide functionality.

**Method 1** :In controller I have used Ext.getCmp('id of each element inside the tabs') and show hide the components in summary tab based on the value entered by the user. This killed my app in IE8 popping a message saying that the "script is slow and blah blah..." i had to click on NO for 5 to 6 times for the summary tab to render and display the page.

**Method 2** :In controller I used ref and selectos to acccess all the items in tabs. I have used itemId for each and every field in summary tab. like `this.getXyz().show()`. I thought it would be fast. Yes it was in Google chrome. but my app in IE8 is slow compared to goolge chrome/firefox

Any suggestions regarding this and plan to decrease page render time. The summary page has more than 1000 fields. Please feel free to shed ur thoughts or throw some ideas on this.

thank you!!

Comment: Have you read this guide? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/performance

Comment: No. I am going through it and what do u think of above problem?..thanks for the link.

Comment: Don't expect a page with thousands of fields to be fast in IE8. It's really that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

up().down().action....did the magic. I have replaced each and every usage of Ext.getCmp('id'). Booooha... it's fast and NO issues.

this.up('tabpanel').down('tabName #itemIdOfField').actions.

actions= hide(), show(), setValues().

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few suggestions you can try. First, to answer your title, I think the fastest simple way to lookup components in javascript is to build a hash map. Something like this:

```
var map = {};
Ext.each(targetComponents, function(item) {
    map[item.itemId] = item;
});

// Fastest way to retrieve a component
var myField = map[componentId];
```

For the rendering time, be sure that the layout/DOM is not updated each time you call `hide` or `show` on a child component. Use [`suspendLayouts`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-suspendLayouts) to do that:

```
summaryTabCt.suspendLayouts();

// intensive hide-and-seek business

// just one layout calculation and subsequent DOM manipulation    
summaryTabCt.resumeLayouts(true);
```

Finally, if despite your best efforts you can't cut on the processing time, do damage control. That is, avoid freezing the UI the whole time, and having the browser telling the user your app is dead.

You can use `setTimeout` to limit the time your script will be holding the execution thread at once. The interval will let the browser some time to process UI events, and prevent it from thinking your script is lost into an infinite loop.

Here's an example:

```
var itemsToProcess = [...],
    // The smaller the chunks, the more the UI will be responsive,
    // but the whole processing will take longer...
    chunkSize = 50,
    i = 0,
    slice;

function next() {
    slice = itemsToProcess.slice(i, i+chunkSize);
    i += chunkSize;
    if (slice.length) {

        Ext.each(slice, function(item) {
            // costly business with item
        });

        // defer processing to give time
        setTimeout(next, 50);
    } else {
        // post-processing
    }
}

// pre-processing (eg. disabling the form submit button)

next(); // start the loop
```

Comment: Rixo, I am trying to check my logic here. Why are the tabs (each tab is of xtype : 'form') flag isDirty() = true..... even if no data is entered? Is it because it was rendered? I have checked all the properties of form for a particular tab. wasDirty : true and isDirty() is set to true. Also, suspendLayouts is osmething whcih i have look into. this is completely new to me. Is it because, I have some default values in form...so the form flags are set to dirty as true? Any info on this please?

Answer (score 0):

- Try to check **deferredRender** is true. This should only render the active tab.
- You also can try a different **hideMode**. Especially **hideMode:'offsets '** sounds promising

Quote from the sencha API:

> hideMode: 'offsets' is often the solution to layout issues in IE specifically when hiding/showing things

As I wrote in the comment, go through this performance guide:  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/performance

In your case, this will be very interesting for you:

```
{
    Ext.suspendLayouts();
    // batch of updates
    // show() / hide() elements
    Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
}
```